# ffmpeg h265 selective decoding issue

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc, h.265

I need to implement selective decoding for live streaming. I need to drop B frame decoding to reduce high cpu utilization. For that I modified "decode_video" in ffmpeg.c file. Looking at the pic_type (=3) , I am dropping the decoding. This change is working fine when feeding input (.ts)  file. But when I am feeding live input using udp:// , extracted (P) frame gets distorted.
Can anyone have any knowledge on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't drop them based on pic_type, all pic_type frames can be references in HEVC. You need to drop them based on [NalUnitType](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/hevc_8h.html#a0149bdce65c87e9ccee137eb54502019) being a non-reference frame (_N is non-reference, _R is a reference). If you're dropping references, all frames using that reference will also become distorted.

Comment: Thanks for the information Ronald. But my doubt is H.265 documents says that I frame is key frame which is not dependent upon any other frame. P frame is dependent upon either I or P frame but not B frame. Then why dropping  of B frame distorting the P frame. Is this information applied in the context of NalUnitType or something else ?

Comment: One more thing one to share, when I am applying same P frame dropping for H.264, the extracted P frame not at all gets distorted.

Comment: Hevc and h264 are very different codecs. I already gave you the solution, drop frames only if the NalUnitType is _N. Did you try that?

Comment: I tried B frame dropping based on NalUnitType. It's working fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Even with these frame dropping there is no significant difference in CPU utilization. Is there any way to drop more frames?

Comment: No. If you want to speed up decoding further, you have choices of decoding frames with non-perfect features (e.g. drop loopfilter/sao, do bilinear MC), or to learn how to speed these things up in ffmpeg's decoder (or hire someone to do that for you). There's massive opportunity for speed optimizations in ffmpeg's hevc decoder.